# Create a hamburger menu with navigation drawer in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, hamburger-menu

I want to create a hamburger menu in android with navigation drawer. I've already developed it but according to the requirements the menu should slide out the base fragment instead of overlapping. I want to develop something like the hamburger menu used by facebook.

1. This is what I require :

[image]

2. This is what I've accomplished:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Instead of NavigationDrawer (which overlaps content), you can use [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library.

Answer (score 7):

Google introduce Material Design with the new guidelines for Navigation Drawer : [official source](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

Some amazing people made library matching this guidelines : https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

If you want to do it yourself : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer