# How to open Navigation Drawer when click on navigation drawer icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How to open Navigation Drawer when click on navigation drawer icon.

> I want open Navigation Drawer like this

![Navigation Drawer][1]

> I added a menu but still not showing

```
toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            DashBordActivity.this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    if (navigationView != null) {
        setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
    }


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
//@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void setupToolbar(String title) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    //revision: this don't works, use setOnChildClickListener() and setOnGroupClickListener() above instead
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

> navigation drawer is not open when i click on the drawer how to solve this problem

is there any code is missing in my code.

Comment: please add your layout file and java file

Comment: Have a look here https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer

Comment: add icon inside item

Comment: in your onCreate, add these:
`Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`
 `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: add margin top(action bar size ) to you drawer layour

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a hamburger menu with navigation drawer in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169832/create-a-hamburger-menu-with-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Comment: the `resId` should be `android.R.id.home` while this does not belong into `menu.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.menu);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawer.openDrawer(START);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/import" />

</group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**This tutorial is very help full like:-**

- Add the navigation drawer layout
- set icon and text in drawer layout

I refer this link

https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

it is very helpful try this